# Pass variable from User Event Script to Client Script in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using 2 scripts to accomplish an email function in NetSuite.  I have a User Event script that creates a button and a client script that pulls all the needed variables and runs the email based on a value found in the Sales Team sublist.  Here is my issue:  When testing the scripts everything worked great because I was testing with my Administrator role (rookie mistake I know).  When a role other than Admin attempts to run the scripts via the button click, an nlObjError is thrown due to role permissions issues (can't pull employee data which is where the email address is stored).  Is it possible to pull all the variables I need in the UE script (which can execute as Admin) and pass those to the client script?

UE Script:

```
function userEventCreateButton(type, form, request){

if (type != 'edit'){
        return;
    }
form.addButton('custpage_RequestSOW', "Request SOW", 'cs_RequestEmail()');
form.setScript('customscript224');
```

Client Script:

```
...for (var y = 1; y <= nlapiGetLineItemCount('salesteam'); y++) {
        var z = nlapiGetLineItemValue('salesteam', 'salesrole', y);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'sales role', z);
        var user = nlapiGetUser();
        **var username = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', user);**
        var firstname = username.getFieldValue('firstname');
        var lastname = username.getFieldValue('lastname');
        var opptitle = nlapiGetFieldValue('title');
        var customer = nlapiGetFieldValue('customer');
        nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'user', user);
        if (z != 5){}
        else if (z == 5){
            var employee_name = nlapiGetLineItemValue('salesteam', 'employee', y);
            console.log(employee_name);
            **var engrecord = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', employee_name);**
            console.log(engrecord);
            var engemail = engrecord.getFieldValue('email');
            console.log(engemail);
            nlapiSendEmail(user...
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is you can add the employees email to the hidden fields in  `before load user event` script which is deployed to run as Administrator and then in your client script you can read the emails

```
//in a variable make a JSON of employee Ids to Emails
newForm.addField('custpage_emails', 'longtext','Email').setDisplayType(hidden).setValue(JSON.stringify(employeeIdEmails));
```

In client script you can now get the data using

```
var emploeeIdToEmails = JSON.parse(nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_emails'));
```

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is have the client side script call a formlesss Suitelet.  The suitelet will be the one to generate and send the email.  If you set the deployment of the Suitelet to Execute As = Administrator, this should resolve the permission issue.

Another solution is to get the data in the Before Load script, put it in a JSON object and store that in a custom field on the record.

Comment: Hi Rusty,  I'm ashamed to say I've never built a Suitelet before so I'm not sure where to start in that script but I've had a few people suggest this as the route to go so I will see if I can get it working.  Thanks for the suggestion.